# I imported numpy using terminal, but the python shell says the that there is no module named numpy

Tags: python, numpy, python-import

I am trying to import numpy. I installed it with pip using.`pip install numpy` it returned: `Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (1.8.0rc1)` When i tested it in python using: `from numpy import *` it returned `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`What happened????

Comment: Do you have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed in your system? `pip install numpy` seems to be installing it for Python 2 (judging by the path numpy is installed in). If you try to run that with Python 3, it won't find the module. Maybe that's not the problem, but that has happened to me in the past in some linux distros where you need to use `pip3 install module`.

Comment: Oh, thanks! 'pip3 install numpy' seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad! Happy coding!